# Find the conditional moments of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have three different variables $x$, $y$ and $z$, where $x$ stands for the state of the world and $\mathbb{X}$ is the state space, such that $x\in\mathbb{X}$. The following information hold

$$s= x + \epsilon\quad\text{where $(x,\epsilon)$ are independently distributed and $x\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$, $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma_{\epsilon}^2)$}$$

$$y= x + \eta\quad\text{where $(x,\eta)$ are independently distributed and $x\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$, $\eta\sim N(0,\sigma_{\eta}^2)$}$$

and $z$ is correlated with the state of the world $x$ such that $z\sim N(\mu_z, \sigma_z^2)$ and $\sigma(z,s)=\sigma(z,y) = Cov(z,x) = \sigma(z,x) \ne 0$. Note that, $(z,\epsilon,\eta)$ are independently distributed.

Let $I=\{s,y,z\}$ be an information set that contains all three random variables. Then, I want to calculate the following conditional moments $\mathbb{E}(x|I)$, $\mathbb{V}ar(x|I)$ and $\mathbb{C}ov(x,z|I)$.

My idea is to use the projection theorem and hence

$$\mathbb{E}(x|I) = \mathbb{E}(x) + \left(\sigma(x,s), \sigma(x, y), \sigma(x, z)\right) \Sigma_I^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
s-\mathbb{E}(s) \\
y- \mathbb{E}(y) \\
z - \mathbb{E}(z)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

such that $\Sigma_I^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{V}ar(s) & \mathbb{C}ov(s,y) & \mathbb{C}ov(s,z)\\
\mathbb{C}ov(y,s) & \mathbb{V}ar(y) & \mathbb{C}ov(y,z)\\
\mathbb{C}ov(z,s)& \mathbb{C}ov(z,y) & \mathbb{V}ar(z)
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$

Then

$$
\mathbb{V}ar(x|I) = \mathbb{V}ar(x) - \left(\sigma(x,s), \sigma(x, y), \sigma(x, z)\right) \Sigma_{I}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma(x,s) \\
\sigma(x, y) \\
\sigma(x, z)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{C}ov(x,z|I) = \Sigma_{(x,z)} - \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_{(x,\{s,y,z\})} \\ \Sigma_{(z,\{s,y,z\})}\end{pmatrix} \Sigma_{I}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_{(x,\{s,y,z\})} \\ \Sigma_{(z,\{s,y,z\})}\end{pmatrix}^\intercal 
 $$

where $\Sigma_{(x,z)} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{V}ar(x) & \mathbb{C}ov(x,z)\\ 
\mathbb{C}ov(z,x) & \mathbb{V}ar(z) \end{pmatrix}$,  $\begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_{(x,\{s,y,z\})} \\ \Sigma_{(z,\{s,y,z\})}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{V}ar(x) & \mathbb{C}ov(x,y) & \mathbb{C}ov(x,z)\\ 
\mathbb{C}ov(z,s) & \mathbb{C}ov(y,z) & \mathbb{V}ar(z)\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and the exponent $^\intercal $ stands for the transpose matrix.

The difficult part is to calculate the inverse matrix of $\Sigma_I^{-1}$. I omit the calculations, but I just want to know if I am at the right direction to find the conditional moments? Could anyone please give me some feedback or tell me if there is an easier way to do the calculations? If the dimension was higher, namely I had four random variables, say $s$, $y$, $z$ and $w$ then the calculations become even more difficult, how could someone respond to such a problem?

Comment: I don't understand what is $\mathbb{E}[X|\{X,Y,Z\}]$?

Comment: @Jan I changed the notation a little bit, but to be clear, $\mathbb{E}(s|I=\{x,y,z\})$ is the conditional expectation of $s$ with respect to the information set $I$. All the variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ are $I$ -  measurable. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Now the question makes more sense. It seems to me that $\mathbb{E}[S|\{X,Y,Z\}]$ equals $\mathbb{E}[S|X]$. The reason is that once you know the realization of $X$, In order to learn about $S=X+\epsilon$, you need to learn about $\epsilon$. Knowing $Y$ tells you what $\eta$ is, but $\eta$ is independent of $\epsilon$. Knowing $Z$ also does not tell you anything about $\epsilon$, since these two are independent. If correct, then, $\mathbb{E}[X+\epsilon|X=x]=x+\mathbb{E}[\epsilon]=x$.

Comment: @jan so this means that $\mathbb{E}(s|I)= \mathbb{E}(s|x) $ and the rest of the variables $y$ and $z$ that also contain some information about $s$ do not play any role to find the conditional moments?

Comment: Sorry I made some changes, please just take a look again.